# Enequeued jobs are not processed by Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq with Rails and Heroku to execute asynchronous workers but I am not able to get it working. I've tried launching those workers manually (executing the perform method) and they work, however when you schedule them and check the Sidekiq webpage they appear as **enqueued** and it doesn't process them.

I'm using an **Heroku** Worker and **Redis To Go** and this is the config:

**sidekiq.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 2 }
end
```

**sidekiq.yml**

```
:concurrency: 2
```

**Worker launch**

```
Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(MyWorker)
```

Sidekiq and Redis seems to be properly connected because I get the following log on Heroku:

```
015-04-27T21:46:51Z 3 TID-ovbydc96k INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {:size=>1, :url=>"redis://redistogo:REDACTED@soapfish.redistogo.com:xxxx/"}
```

I'm missing something but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you specified queue while starting sidekiq?

Comment: I've specified the queues in the .yml file. Should I do it on a different way? @Sanjiv

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this command so that Sidekiq knows to use the Redis-To-Go URL?

`heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL`

Comment: Yes I did, in fact it connects to Redis

Comment: Then it is likely that you have the job in a non-default queue which Sidekiq is not processing.